# How to restrict SSH login post ssh-copy-id

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, openssh

**Environment:-**

```
Server–1
Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.7, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
```

```
Server-2
Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
OpenSSH_7.6p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
```

From `Server-1` executed `ssh-copy-id admin@server-2`

Now from `Server-1` passwordless `ssh` connection works as expected to connect `server-2` using `ssh admin@server-2` command.

**Requirement:-**

1. I want to restrict `ssh admin@server-2` login from `server-1`.
2. Since I have already executed `ssh-copy-id admin@server-2` in `server-1`, I should prevent only `ssh admin@server-2` login.

Please let me know is there any way available to prevent?

Comment: Not quite clear, what your intention is. Do you want to enable `admin@server-2` logins for users ONLY if they have the private ssh-key? Or do you want to prohibit the login for this account ONLY from `server-1`?

Comment: I believe you want to login to Server-2 from Server-1, but to prevent any access from Server-2 in to Server-1?

If that is a correct interpretation of the situation, then you don't necessarily have to do anything else. 
 
As long as there is no SSH key copied on to Server-1 from Server-2, then Server 2 will not be able to login to Server-1 by default.

Comment: @ForeverCuber, I have data in server-2 that data I can able to pull/fetch using ssh from server-1, but ssh login from server-1 to server-2 need to be blocked.

Answer (score 1):

on `server-2` you need to modify `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add:

```
AllowUsers admin@server-1
```

that will allow only login to user `admin` from `server-1`

Also, not sure, but if you would like really hardcore, you can also allow only logins without password, same in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

and restart sshd daemon

```
systemsctl restart sshd
```

I would recommend login with one sell, do changes, do restart of sshd and open new terminal, and try connectivity, so if it would not work, you could revert changes.